# Get Route in ServiceStack RequestFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have a FilterAttribute in my MVC 4 + ServiceStack app like so:

```
public class AuthSignatureRequired : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.RequestFilterAttribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
```

Users can access routes like this:

```
[Route("/apple/locations/", Verbs = "GET")]
[Route("/apple/locations/{Region}", Verbs = "GET")]
```

How can I get the route from within my `AuthSignatureRequired()` request filter attribute?

For instance, how can I get "apple" from the URI above?

I have tried this which works, but is there a better way?

```
req.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "").Split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the routes variable placeholders like `{Region}` from the populated request DTO. For the rest of the PathInfo you should get it from `req.PathInfo`.

Comment: You recommend using a placeholder instead of using the method I use above?  Do you have an example of how to do what you recommend, please?